# Error hiding app icon after asking permitions in Android Manifest xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I made an app to automatically hide its icon after launched.
I used this code to make this system

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Everything works fine until I try to request permissions in my Android Manifest XML,
for example

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

on asking the permission the app ignores the script and it doesn't hide the icon

> Note: the only error is that my app doesn't hide, the rest of the app works perfectly.

Comment: "i made an app to automatically hide its icon after launched" -- note that this will not work on newer versions of Android.

Comment: When you're asking permissions from the manifest regarding things that communicate with other apps the package can't be hidden. Could you check if it is the same with just the internet permission?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it with internet permission only, Gave me the same error, not hiding. And i need it for my app, if it can't be done, i will have to stop working on it